# First order Differential Equation. How to bring it to standard form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this eq. in Agarwal: Ordinary and Partial diff. equations book.

$$(y^2-1) + 2(x-y(1+y)^2)y'=0 $$

Is there a clever substitution to bring this to standard form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ you will get in the form
$$\frac{dx}{dy} + xP(y) = Q(y)$$
which is the first order linear differential equation.
$$ \frac{dx}{dy} - 2x\frac{1}{1-y^2} = - y\frac{(1+y)^2}{(1-y^2)}$$
integrating factor $\to e^{\int {P(y)dy}}$
solution is
$$x e^{\int {P(y)dy}} = \int {Q(y) e^{\int {P(y)dy}} } +C$$

Comment: Thanks very much. Btw, there is a minus in front of the dx/dy.

Comment: you are welcome. i have edited the mistake.